# Changing a Single Cell Range to Column Range

Tags: vba, excel

The below code works but now I need it to work for column range instead of only a single cell range.
    I need to substitute:

CJ3 single cell to CJ column (starting on row 3);

CK3 single cell to CK column (starting on row 3);

CM3 single cell to CM column (starting on row 3);

CN3 single cell to CN column (starting on row 3);

CO3 single cell to CO column (starting on row 3).

Please can anyone help?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("CJ3").Value = "FOLLOW UP" And Range("CM3").Value = "" And Range("CN3").Value = "" Then
        Range("CO3").Value = "FOLLOW UP"
    ElseIf Range("CJ3").Value = "FOLLOW UP" And Range("CM3").Value > 0 And Range("CN3").Value = "" Then
        Range("CO3").Value = "AWAITING APPROVAL"
    ElseIf Range("CJ3").Value = "FOLLOW UP" And Range("CM3").Value > 0 And Range("CN3").Value > 0 Then
        Range("CO3").Value = "CLOSED"
    ElseIf Range("CJ3").Value = "NO FOLLOW UP" And Range("CN3").Value = "" Then
        Range("CO3").Value = "AWAITING APPROVAL"
        Range("CK3:CM3").Value = "N/A"
    ElseIf Range("CJ3").Value = "NO FOLLOW UP" And Range("CN3").Value > 0 Then
        Range("CO3").Value = "CLOSED"
        Range("CK3:CM3").Value = "N/A"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You probably want to "loop through each cell in a column". That is a very common task and code for it is often asked by beginners. You might google for the term I have placed between quotation marks.

Comment: I have tried "loop through each cell in a column" but it slowed the sheet down. Example: Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Rows.Count
If Cells(i, 88).Value = "FOLLOW UP" And Cells(i, 91).Value = "" And Cells(i, 92).Value = "" Then
Cells(i, 93).Value = "FOLLOW UP"  
End If
Next i
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to specify the worksheet your code should work on. It is the ActiveSheet by default. Therefore my code below is hardly different from yours. The difference is in that it is written down specifically, and that will help you understand your own code and, therefore, speed up trouble-shooting (which always takes more time than writing the code, anyway). You could also specify another sheet. For example, `Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")`. That would be much better because the code couldn't be made to do its magic on another sheet by mistake.

So, this is what your code might now look like.

```
Private Sub TryLoop()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row
    Dim R As Long                               ' row

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 1 To Rl
            If .Cells(R, 88).Value = "FOLLOW UP" And .Cells(R, 91).Value = "" And .Cells(R, 92).Value = "" Then
                .Cells(R, 93).Value = "FOLLOW UP"
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

`Rows.Count` returns the number of rows in the active sheet (or `Ws` if it is specified). Depending upon the version of Excel you use that would be at least 65,000 rows. Yes, that would take some time to loop through. Therefore the above cover limits the looping to those rows which actually have a value in column 1 (which is column "A"). You could also write this line like this, `Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.

Now I think your code is perfect. What is it that it doesn't do?

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will try your code. My code is in Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range). Each time I select a different cell in that sheet, it's taking forever.

Comment: You don't want the code to run whenever you click somewhere. That's why you should limit its scope. The event procedure's `Target` argument holds the cell that was clicked. You could say something like `If Target.Column <> 88 Then Exit Sub`. Or use `Application.Intersect` for the same purpose. Consider using the Change event instead of Selection_Change if you want the code to run only when you make a change, and then limit its action in the same way, depending upon wether the change occurred in a cell which is significant for the "Follow Up".

Comment: Works perfectly!!! Thank you for all your good suggestions and kind help. On the code above, the line "Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row"  I had to change to "Rl = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row" without the end punctuation before Cells and Rows.

Comment: Sorry about that. Without the leading period theRl is set according to the `ActiveSheet` which may be different from `Ws`. I corrected the mistake in the above code to move the line into the `With Ws` statement.

Comment: @Variatus don't you find it easier to use `.Range("CJ" & R).Value` instead of `.Cells(R, 88).Value` ? etc..

Comment: @Rai Rado - No. Defining a range using Excel notations in VBA is the more cumbersome the more manipulation you need to do. It's like eating noodles with chopsticks.